# Convert array to comma-delimited text

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Apologies for this embarassingly simple question but I'm still relatively new to javascript.

I have an array of names, something like

```
var myArray = ['Hill M','Zhang F','Dong L', 'Wilkinson JS', 'Harris N'];
```

I would like to return a string, with names separated by commas, but with "and" between the final two names, i.e.

```
'Hill M, Zhang F, Dong L, Wilkinson JS and Harris N'
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in javascript?

How about if I wanted to transpose the names and initials, i.e. to return

```
'M Hill, F Zhang, L Dong, JS Wilkinson and N Harris'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Array::slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) Selects a part of an array, and returns the new array.
[Array::join()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) Joins all elements of an array into a string
[String::concat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) Concatenates two or more strings.

```
var myArray = ['Hill M','Zhang F','Dong L', 'Wilkinson JS', 'Harris N'];

console.log(myArray.slice(0, myArray.length - 1).join(', ').concat(
            ' and ' + myArray[myArray.length - 1]));

//Hill M, Zhang F, Dong L, Wilkinson JS and Harris N
```

To change their order:

```
var myArray = ['Hill M','Zhang F','Dong L', 'Wilkinson JS', 'Harris N'];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
  myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace(/^(\S+)\s+(.+)$/, '$2 $1');

console.log(myArray.slice(0, myArray.length - 1).join(', ').concat(
            ' and ' + myArray[myArray.length - 1]));

//M Hill, F Zhang, L Dong, JS Wilkinson and N Harris
```

In case you are wondering about `str.replace(/^(\S+)\s+(.+)$/, '$2 $1');`

`/^(\S+)\s+(.+)$/` is regular expression that matches a string that:

```
^    #starts with  
\S+  #one or more non whitespace characters, followed by  
\s+  #one or more whitespace characters, followed by  
.+   #one or more characters
```

`$1` and `$2` in the replacement string stands for 1st and 2nd groups (subpatterns enclosed in parentheses) from the regex.

Comment: It's good, but give some explanation, perhaps? OP said he was new to js.

Comment: That works brilliantly - thanks very much. Only slight problem is the second part (reversal/transposition) fails for names such as "Ben Gaied N", but I didn't explicitly ask about that, and I'm sure I can sort that out.

Comment: @Tomba the regex currently swaps the words at first whitespace. Use `/(.+)\s+(\S+)/` to swap at the last whitespace.

Comment: poetry, except it fails when array contains zero or one elements. trivial to fix. thx!

Comment: Can you please share a if array contains one element ?

Comment: It fails when array contains 1 element

Answer (score 8):

Use **[join](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Join)** for combining the values in the array.

```
var myJoinedString = myArray.join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = ['Hill M','Zhang F','Dong L', 'Wilkinson JS', 'Harris N'];
var replaced = myArray.map(function(elem) {
  return elem.replace(/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/, "$2 $1");
});
var last = replaced.pop()
var result = replaced.join(", ") + " and " + last;

alert(result)
```

Comment: Nice, but you might want to use `/^(.*?)\s+(\S+)$`/ for your expression instead

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (myArray.length <= 1) {
    str = myArray.join();
} else {
    str = myArray.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " and " + myArray[myArray.length-1];
}
```

And for your swapping part:

```
myArray.map(function(val) { return val.split(" ").reverse().join(" "); })
```